# Как сложность алгоритмов связана со скоростью?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Есть код

```
var a = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a++;
    a++;
    a++;
}
```

И есть код

```
var a = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a += 3;
}
```

Сложность обоих алгоритмов O(n), но блин...

Понятно, что любой адекватный компилятор схлопнет первый вариант во второй, но бывают и не столь очевидные случаи, поэтому предположим, что компилятор таки не сделает этого.

В итоге получается, что второй код выполнится в 3 раза быстрее первого. Но сложность одинаковая. Как в этом случае "научно" обосновать, что первый код -
 какашка?

Comment: @Igor можно чуть проще?

Comment: @Igor Это я и так знаю. Вы на вопрос не ответили

Comment: В ответе должно присутствовать слово "какашка", чтобы он Вас удовлетворил?

Comment: @Igor, вы на вопрос так и не ответили :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

То, о чем вы говорите - это вопрос "константы в O-выражении".

В вашем *простейшем* случае вы просто *теоретически* оцениваете, что время выполнения (количество вычислений) оказывается выше. В более сложных случаях (да даже в таких вот простейших!) требуется нормальный хронометраж, потому что вполне может оказаться из-за каких-то особенностей архитектуры или компилятора, как вы выразились, "какашкой" тот код, который вам представляется лучшим.

Comment: Вот же ж :) Спасибо.

Comment: Корменна надо почитать. Даже "научпоп" книгу, которую везде продают, урезанная версия обычной книги.

Answer (score 2):

Сложность кода в контексте Вашего вопроса говорит не о том, как быстро работает код по сравнению с другим кодом, a о том, как изменяется время выполнения при масштабировании задачи - и только.

Например, есть код, который обрабатывает все элементы матрицы размером `n` на `n`. Число `n` представляет собой характеристику размера задачи. Код может увеличивать все элементы на единицу (быстрее) или вычислять их экспоненты (медленнее), но его сложность в обоих случаях - `O(n^2)`. При изменении `n` время выполнения изменится пропорционально квадрату изменения `n`.

Comment: Я не спрашивал о чем говорит сложность кода, я задал конкретный вопрос. "Как в этом случае "научно" обосновать, что первый код - какашка?"

Comment: Я привел в пример сложность алгоритма при масштабируемости, чтобы показать на то, что вот оно научное обоснование для масштабируемости. Но в случае с двумя вариантами кода видно, что второй выполняется быстрее. Как это научно обосновать?